# C# Timer struct

Tags: c#, timer

Hello I have a small problem.

I'm using a Time structure, if I set the seconds to 100, it must give me an output (in console): 1 minute and 40 seconds.

```
struct Time
    {
        Time Timer = new Time(100);
        public Timer(int seconds);
        public Timer(int minutes, int seconds);
        public Timer(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
    }
```

I'm having this, but it gives me an error:
"Method must have a return type"
"AudioDevices.Tracks.Track.Time does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"

Full code:

```
public class Track
{
    int id;
    string name;
    string artist;
    string albumSource;

    enum Category
    {
        Ambient, Blues, Country, Disco, Electro, Hardcore, HardRock,
        HeavyMetal, Hiphop, Jazz, Jumpstyle, Klassiek, Latin, Other,
        Pop, Punk, Reggae, Rock, Soul, Trance, Techno,
    }

    struct Time
    {
        Time Timer = new Time(100);
        public Timer(int seconds);
        public Timer(int minutes, int seconds);
        public Timer(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
    }
}
```

}

If able, could you please explain how you did it?

Comment: How are you expecting to be able to have a field called `Timer` and methods called `Timer`? And how are you expecting to embed one value of type `Time` within the `Time` struct? And why are you not just using `TimeSpan`?

Comment: Instead of using your `Timer/Time` struct, isn't better to use a `TimeSpan`?

Answer (score 1):

Either specify return types to methods, or change method name from `Timer` to `Time`

i.e. Change following

```
    public Timer(int seconds);
    public Timer(int minutes, int seconds);
    public Timer(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
```

to

```
    public Time(int seconds);
    public Time(int minutes, int seconds);
    public Time(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
```

Comment: Alright! That indeed has worked. But now I have 1 problem left: "AudioDevices.Tracks.Track.Time does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments" Thanks for the first one!

Comment: Where are you defining the implementation. Also as you are specifying public to ctor, the struct should also be public.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent the duration of the track, use timespan...see the example here...

```
TimeSpan TrackDuration= new TimeSpan(3, 01, 59);
Console.WriteLine(TrackDuration.ToString());
```

For example (Edit): **I have amended so you can pass seconds as int if needed**

```
public class Track
        {
            internal enum Category
            {
                Ambient, Blues, Country, Disco, Electro,  Hardcore,
                HardRock, HeavyMetal, Hiphop, Jazz, Jumpstyle, Klassiek, Latin, 
                Other, Pop, Punk, Reggae, Rock, Soul, Trance, Techno
            }

            public Track(int id, string name, string artist, 
                         string albumSource, Category category, 
                          TimeSpan duration, int seconds)
            {
                Id = id;
                Name = name;
                Artist = artist;
                AlbumSource = albumSource;
                TrackCategory = category;
                Duration = duration;
                Seconds = seconds;
            }

            public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }

            public Category TrackCategory { get; set; }

            public string AlbumSource { get; set; }

            public string Artist { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public int Id { get; set; }

            public int Seconds { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Seconds);
            return string.Format("{0} by {1} is {2} long - 
                            using seconds {3:%m} Minutes {3:%s} Seconds", 
                                Name, Artist, Duration, ts);
              }
        }
```

and then use like this...

```
var track = new Track(1, "Song 1", "Artist name", "Album name", 
             Track.Category.Blues, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3, 59), 100);

Console.WriteLine(track.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I haven't explained myself well, but I'm  using a library class instead of a console class. How am I able to output now while I can't make use of "Console.WriteLine"?

Comment: just use `track.ToString()`, I was just giving this as an example.  When you create a new track object, the `.ToString()` will return the format you want, you can alter the `ToString` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a `TimeSpan` instead of creating a new type to hold a time duration. You can avoid problems fommating that TimeSpan (which doesn't implement `IFormattable`) by using a `DateTime` like below:

```
public class Track
{
    public int      Id       { get; set; }
    public string   Name     { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}. {1} ({2:mm'm'ss's'})",
             this.Id, this.Name, DateTime.MinValue.Add(this.Duration));
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tracks = new[]
    { 
        new Track { Id = 1, Name = "Song #1", Duration = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:30") /* 01m30s */ },
        new Track { Id = 2, Name = "Song #2", Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45)   /* 00m45s */ },
        new Track { Id = 3, Name = "Song #3", Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 45)     /* 02m45s */ }
    };

    foreach (var track in tracks)
        Console.WriteLine(track);
}
```